# Temporarily disable popups on Android (Facebook, Snapchat, LINE, etc)

Tags: gratis, android, privacy, notification, widget

I often show my phone screen to people:

- to show an app to my boss
- to show my vacation pictures to a relative
- etc

Unknowingly, other friends send me very personal messages at the same time, and they appear on the screen, resulting in awkward moments:

[image: Snapchat popup][image: Facebook Messenger popup]

---

Is there an app to disable these popups?

Requirements:

- Widget to disable/enable **with a single touch**.
- Free, ideally open source.
- Block popups from Facebook Messenger at least. Bonus if it disables all communication apps popups.

Note:

- Disabling for N minutes/hours is OK too.
- Having notifications appear in the status bar is OK as long as the content is not shown.
- Requiring root is OK, but bonus if not.

Comment: You might be interested in my list of [apps for notifications](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_notifications). I'm not using any of them, but there might be an alternative that's more intuitive (well, do not pick anything like "voice notifications" – that might worsen your situation :) [DND Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.root.dndnotification.off) (DoNotDisturb) sounds like a good candidate. Or [ShutApp - Pause Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=shutapp.shutapp) (matches your description, see "case 2" :)

Comment: @Izzy: I just had a look at these two, they need more than one touch unfortunately (if you count the one to start the app).

Comment: Have you checked whether they might have a suitable widget/shortcut to toggle a profile? With "some other app", one could integrate such things even in the notification area, and then wouldn't even have to go to the home-screen (or app drawer). AFAIR there were even some with Tasker support, so you could trigger it based on locations/events/foreground-app etc. Just thinking aloud – as I wrote, I don't use any such app.

Comment: Just an idea, would turning data off be acceptable? You might be able to find something that can disable data (but not phone calls) for a certain time. Flight mode would work but is a bit extreme.

Comment: @KERR: I must be able to continue using data, especially when I show a web-based app to my boss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) for that.

1. Create a macro that calls the "Configure App Notifications" action, muting the apps you want. Set its trigger to the red button.
2. Create the opposite macro, also with the "Configure App Notifications" action. Set its trigger to the green button.
3. Add the red and green widget button to your home.

Gratis (within MacroDroid's 5 macros free tier).
Not sure whether it needs root or not. I can only say it works with root, please comment with the result if you try without root, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff), it is not very intuitive but works great.

1) Create your profiles by unchecking the apps whose popups you want to block:

[image: Notifications Off configuration]

2) Add widgets for each profile:

[image: Notifications Off widget]

Gratis. Needs root.